# Selector Outline not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to customize the outline when a selector is focused using the following

```
*:focus { 
  outline: green dotted 1px;
}
```

But what I see from Chrome is still displaying a solid blue outline. Tried other browsers they all behave differently. Am I making any mistakes on the outline CSS declaration?

Comment: Do you have any link to share for this issue?

Comment: Works for me: http://cssdeck.com/labs/zhsclahz

More details and test case, please.

Comment: Why are you suprised at a blue outline when [`#0099FF`](http://www.colorhexa.com/0099ff) is a blue-ish colour?

Comment: @George Sorry I've edited to make my question clear.

Comment: This is probably a [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity) issue. Perhaps another selector overrides this one within your stylesheet. You could verify that by checking the Dev tool panel on Chrome/FF.

Answer (score 2):

It should work, http://jsfiddle.net/9yzsf8pq/1/

```
<style>
*:focus { 
  outline: #0099FF dotted 1px;
}                            
</style>

<input type=submit>
<a href="">dasdsa</a>
```

In all browsers the outline is lightblue and dotted.

Comment: @panther Your answer is fine but it's wrong in my site. Searched throughout the site it hasn't been declared anywhere else. Anyway I've added !important so it looks all good now. Thanks for the hint anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand the problem. #0099FF is hex for the colour blue. Also 1px is very small so maybe it just looks blue?

Try 3px as a test.

Are you working on a live server? Css files often cache. Try something like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?Wednesday1" />
```

This will force a refresh.